# MS Word Drop down list or combo box from MS Access Database

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-word

I'm trying to populate a combo box or drop down list from an access database. I used the following website for code template. I modified it to suit my needs. I keep getting the error: 5941 The requested member of the collection does not exist"

Source code: http://www.fontstuff.com/mailbag/qword02.htm

My Code:

```
Private Sub Document_Open()
    On Error GoTo Document_Open_Err

    Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset

    cnn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=*path to database removed for post*;"
    rst.Open "SELECT DISTINCT TOP 25 [Equipment] FROM tblEquipment ORDER BY [Equipment];", _
        cnn, adOpenStatic
    rst.MoveFirst

    With ActiveDocument.FormFields("Equipment").DropDown.ListEntries
        .Clear
        Do
            .Add rst![Equipment]
            rst.MoveNext
        Loop Until rst.EOF
    End With
Document_Open_Exit:
    On Error Resume Next
    rst.Close
    cnn.Close
    Set rst = Nothing
    Set cnn = Nothing
    Exit Sub
Document_Open_Err:
    MsgBox Err.Number & vbCrLf & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error!"
    Resume Document_Open_Exit
End Sub
```

Code that almost works:

```
Private Sub Document_Open()
    On Error GoTo Document_Open_Err

    Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset

    cnn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=*removed for post*;"
    rst.Open "SELECT DISTINCT TOP 25 [Field1] FROM Equipment_List ORDER BY [Field1];", _
        cnn, adOpenStatic
    rst.MoveFirst

    With ActiveDocument.FormFields("Equipment").DropDown.ListEntries
        .Clear
        Do
            .Add rst![Field1]
            rst.MoveNext
        Loop Until rst.EOF
    End With
Document_Open_Exit:
    On Error Resume Next
    rst.Close
    cnn.Close
    Set rst = Nothing
    Set cnn = Nothing
    Exit Sub
Document_Open_Err:
    MsgBox Err.Number & vbCrLf & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error!"
    Resume Document_Open_Exit
End Sub
```

Comment: What line throws the error?

Comment: `rst` doesn't have a Field named "Equipment" Try something like `"SELECT DISTINCT TOP 25 [Equipment] as Equipment FROM tblEquipment...`  Test your query first, and check the column names in the results are what you expect

Comment: what kind of "combobox" did you place in the Word document? There's more than one kind. Most likely you didn't use a form field, but something else. Maybe a content control?

Comment: Thank you all so much for the quick replies. Answers below

Comment: What line throws the error? -------I do not know. How do I check this?

Comment: what kind of "combobox" did you place in the Word document? There's more than one kind. Most likely you didn't use a form field, but something else. Maybe a content control? ------------------Yes, I am using a content control, do you recommend another method?

Comment: rst doesn't have a Field named "Equipment" Try something like "SELECT DISTINCT TOP 25 [Equipment] as Equipment FROM tblEquipment... Test your query first, and check the column names in the results are what you expect ----------------I will try this and let you know

Comment: Private Sub Document_Open()
    On Error GoTo Document_Open_Err
    
    Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset
    
    cnn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=**;"
    rst.Open "SELECT DISTINCT TOP 25 [Field1] as Equipment_List FROM Equipment_List ORDER BY [Field1];", _
        cnn, adOpenStatic
    rst.MoveFirst
    
    With ActiveDocument.ContentControl("Equipment").DropDown.ListEntries
        .Clear
        Do
            .Add rst![Field1]
            rst.MoveNext
        Loop Until rst.

Comment: Field: Field1
Table: Equipment_List
Dropdown: Content Control Dropdown named "Equipment"

Error: -2147217904 No value for given parameters

Comment: Ok I got it to partially work with using a form field rather than a using content control and getting the name right. Now the issue is the dropdown box just fills with the first value, there is no dropdown to select other items.

Comment: Is there any way to use a combo box or a better dropdown? The form field box will only populate the first value and I cannot change it

Comment: To find the error line, change `On Error GoTo Document_Open_Err` to `On Error GoTo 0` so it will break on the error line.

Comment: Some tips for using the site that would have gotten you responses and possibly even answers much sooner: 1) you need to "ping" people by using the`@` plus their name - @Zed - otherwise there's no notification. 2) Use the [edit] link to put additional, relevant information into the question itself. It's impossible to keep track or properly read code in comments. Do this, ping me, and I might be able to help as this is a Word problem, not an Access one.

Comment: @Andre - just tagging per cindy's recomendation

Comment: @TimWilliams- just tagging per cindy's recomendation

Comment: @ryguy72- just tagging per cindy's recomendation

Comment: Zed, could you click the "flag" next to the comments that are no longer relevant to the question and choose to remove them as "no longer needed"? It's difficult to tell what is or is not working, at this point.

Comment: Zed, I notice that `.Add rst![Field1]` does not specify *what* should be coming from this field. Should it be `Value`, as in `.Add rst![Field1].Value`? I also recommend you remove `On Error Resume Next` as it's very important to know whether these objects are closed and correctly released. You might want to put a Break Point at the `Do` loop then use F8 to step through it. Does it loop more than once?

Answer (score 0):

I'm updating my last post here.  See the code below; set a reference to DAO and make a couple minor tweaks to suit your needs.

```
Option Explicit
'Requires a reference to the '"Microsoft DAO 3.51 (or 3.6) Object Library."
Private Sub Userform_Initialize()
Dim myDataBase As DAO.Database
Dim myActiveRecord As DAO.Recordset
Dim i As Long
  'Open the database to retrieve data
  Set myDataBase = OpenDatabase("D:\Data Stores\sourceAccess.mdb")
  'Define the first recordset
  Set myActiveRecord = myDataBase.OpenRecordset("Table1", dbOpenForwardOnly)
  'Set the listbox column count
  ListBox1.ColumnCount = myActiveRecord.Fields.Count
  i = 0
  'Loop through all the records in the table until the EOF marker is reached.
  Do While Not myActiveRecord.EOF
    'Use .AddItem method to add a new row for each record
    ListBox1.AddItem
    ListBox1.List(i, 0) = myActiveRecord.Fields("Employee Name")
    ListBox1.List(i, 1) = myActiveRecord.Fields("Employee DOB")
    ListBox1.List(i, 2) = myActiveRecord.Fields("Employee ID")
    i = i + 1
    'Get the next record
    myActiveRecord.MoveNext
  Loop
  'Close the database and clean-up
  myActiveRecord.Close
  myDataBase.Close
  Set myActiveRecord = Nothing
  Set myDataBase = Nothing
lbl_Exit:
  Exit Sub
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim oRng As Word.Range
Dim oBM As Bookmarks
  Set oBM = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks
  Set oRng = oBM("EmpName").Range
  oRng.Text = ListBox1.Text
  oBM.Add "EmpName", oRng
  Set oRng = oBM("EmpDOB").Range
  oRng.Text = ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListIndex, 1)
  oBM.Add "EmpDOB", oRng
  Set oRng = oBM("EmpID").Range
  oRng.Text = ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListIndex, 2)
  oBM.Add "EmpID", oRng
  Me.Hide
lbl_Exit:
  Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Code Source:

https://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/populate_userform_listbox_or_combobox.html

Comment: This information is irrelevant to the content of the question. The dropdown is in Word, not Access.

Comment: Oh, I see.  I just updated my original post.  @Zed: try the solution that I just posted.  I did a quick test and it worked fine for me.